# How to select string between two specific characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some classname which I get them like this:

```
var classname = $(this).attr("class");
```

Here is a two examples of those them:

```
fa fa-bold
fa fa-bell-o separator
```

Now I need to these results:

```
bold
bell-o
```

---

The clue is: everything after `fa-` and before  . How can I do that?

Comment: If that is the criteria then the first string would match right? Since there is no `' '` after `'bold'`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, sometimes there is nothing after what I want (so the clue will be everything after `fa-` and before or `' '` or end of line)

Comment: `str.split("fa-")[1].split(" ")[0];`

Comment: @dandavis Well thanks, please write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The clue is: everything after `fa-` and before . How can I do that?

You could capture all non-space characters after `fa-`:

```
/fa-(\S+)/
```

Then use the `.match()` method:

```
var match = 'fa fa-bell-o separator'.match(/fa-(\S+)/);
var result = match ? match[1] : null;
// "bell-o"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\w+\s+\w+)(?=-)-|\s\w+$/g` to match word followed by space followed by `-` or space followed by word followed by end of line

`str.replace(/(\w+\s+\w+)(?=-)-|\s\w+$/g, "")`

Comment: Doesn't work as well, This returns `mob` for this `fa fa-header hidden-mob` while I want this: `header`

Comment: @Alex _"This returns -mob for this fa fa-header hidden-mob"_ Returns `"mob"` , here, though `fa fa-header hidden-mob` not described at Question ? Tried with `classNames`s described at OP ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought just those two examples are enough. anyway thanks for your solution.